# Spring Cloud Contract ContractVerifierTest.java not generated

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

So I'm trying to write contracts in Java, but the problem is that the verifying tests are not running at all. I've tried writing contracts in Groovy and it runs fine, I don't know what's the difference.

Is there some configuration I'm missing for the plugin? I'm following an example project from [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/main/producer_java/pom.xml).

This is the `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>contract_producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>contract_producer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
                    <baseClassForTests>
                        com.example.contract_producer.contracts.BaseTest
                    </baseClassForTests>
                    <contractsDirectory>src/test/java/contracts</contractsDirectory>
                    <depedencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
                            <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </depedencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the contract written in Java

```
package contracts;

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class UserControllerContracts implements Supplier<Contract> {
    @Override
    public Contract get() {
        return Contract.make(new Consumer<Contract>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Contract c) {
                c.name("Get All User Contract");
                c.description("Contract for /users and /user/all");
                
                c.request(request -> {
                    request.method(request.GET());
                    request.url("/user/all");
                });
    
                c.response(response -> {
                    response.status(response.OK());
                    response.body("[{\"id\":1,\"email\":\"user@email.com\",\"password\":\"password\",\"name\":\"User\"}]");
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public static class User {
        Integer id;
        String email;
        String password;
        String name;

        public User(Integer id, String email, String password, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the contract written in Groovy

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description 'Should return all user in database'

    request {
        method GET()
        url '/user/all'
    }

    response {
        status OK()
        headers {
            contentType applicationJson()
        }
        body '''
            [{
                "id": 1,
                "email": "user@email.com",
                "password": "password",
                "name": "User"
            }]
        '''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong version of the plugin. Look that you're using contract in version 3.0.x through the 2020.0.x release train plugin. Since the old plugin generates junit4 tests the latest boot doesn't run it. Just upgrade the plugin to the latest 3.0.x version.

Comment: So I've set the release train to be 2020.0.4 and the contract version to 3.0.4 based on [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes)

But it's still not running, reading the maven log infos I came accross this
```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ contract_producer ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory \contract_producer\target\generated-test-resources\contracts
```

Isn't this the goal that's supposed to run the tests?

Comment: Should the ContractVerifierTest.java be generated under `target\generated-test-sources\contracts\com\example\contract_producer\contracts\ContractVerifierTest.java` or `target\generated-test-sources\contracts\ContractVerifierTest.java`?

Comment: It will not run tests it will generate tests in a folder depending on your maven setup